# Datanode decommisioning vs Write

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

What happens when we decommission a datanode while write is happening to HDFS on that node?

Will it stop writing the data to HDFS on that node and decommision that node or will it finish writing and then decommision it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this in cloudera.

Decommissioning applies to only to HDFS DataNode, MapReduce TaskTracker, YARN NodeManager, and HBase RegionServer roles. If the host has other roles running on it, those roles are stopped/killed.

[http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cm_mc_decomm_host.html](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cm_mc_decomm_host.html)

Answer (score 0):

As staded at the [Hadoop wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/FAQ#I_want_to_make_a_large_cluster_smaller_by_taking_out_a_bunch_of_nodes_simultaneously._How_can_this_be_done.3F):

*Hadoop offers the decommission feature to retire a set of existing data-nodes. The nodes to be retired should be included into the exclude file, and the exclude file name should be specified as a configuration parameter dfs.hosts.exclude. This file should have been specified during namenode startup.*

The exclude file property names a file that contains a list of hosts that are not permitted to connect to the namenode.

When that occurs, I think an `IOException` is gotten by the process writting to the decommissioned node.

Comment: Hi. my question is , when the data is being writen, what happens if we decommision node at that time?

Comment: I think the writer receives an IOException since the files within the Datanode are added to the exclude file.

Comment: According to cloudera , all the jobs will be stoped in datanode.

Answer (score 0):

After you add the entries for the nodes that you want to decommission. You need to execute **namenode -refreshnodes** command to start actual process of decommission. Actual process of decomission is very slow. All the current tasks either read/write will continue as per usual. But all future writes are not allowed but reads are allowed with least priority. Meanwhile all the blocks are replicated to other nodes.